# Reevaluation of a boolean expression in a Javascript loop

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, boolean, expression

could somebody help me get sense of the following issue with this JavaScript code:

```
let x = 2;
let condition = (x > 0);
do {
     console.log("inside do while loop: x is " + x);
     x = -1;
    console.log(condition);
} while (condition);
```

I would expect the following output:

> inside do while loop: x is 2
>
> false

instead I get an endless loop:

> inside do while loop: x is 2
>
> true
>
> inside do while loop: x is -1
>
> true
>
> inside do while loop: x is -1
>
> true

it seems that the boolean expression does not get reevaluated but keeps holding on to x = 2. Anybody got an idea about the general principle at work here?

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: `condition` is calculated before loop. It is not supposed to re-evaluate upon every next reference because it is an expression and not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement

```
let condition = (x > 0);
```

is evaluated **once**.  That's the way statements work in JavaScript and in many very common languages like it. That *assignment* of the value of `(x > 0)` alters the value of the variable `condition`, and that's that. There's no permanent relationship established between `condition` and `x` or any other variable. In other words, that statement means

> Compare `x` to 0, and if it is greater set the value of `condition` to `true`, otherwise to `false`.

It **does not** mean

> Make the `condition` variable always show whether `x` is greater than zero.

In JavaScript, the way to make code reusable is to create *functions*.

Answer (score 0):

The condition is just evaluated before start the do while loop, so, to avoid the infinite loop you are having you need to evaluate the condition:

```
let x = 2;
let condition = (x > 0);
do {
     console.log("inside do while loop: x is " + x);
     x = -1;
    console.log(condition);
    condition = (x > 0);
} while (condition);
```

Answer (score 0):

JS is a sequential programming language, which means it does the lines one by one except if there is a loop or if statemenet or sth like this, so of course the expression will not reevaluate itself, you should but the expression inside the "do while"

```
 let x = 2;
do {
  console.log("inside do while loop: x is " + x);
 x = -1;
 console.log(condition);
 let condition = (x > 0);
} while (condition);
```

or just make it the condition for the loop

```
 let x = 2;
do {
  console.log("inside do while loop: x is " + x);
 x = -1;
 console.log(x > 0);
} while (x > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

After you assign your variable it will stay the same for every time you call it, there are many ways to change such behaviour:

Request if `x > 0` every time after a loop:

```
do {
     console.log("inside do while loop: x is " + x);
     x = -1;
     console.log(condition);
} while (x > 0);
```

or write a function to evaluate a variable:

```
var greaterZero = function(v) {return v>0}

do {
    console.log("inside do while loop: x is " + x);
     x = -1;
 console.log(condition);
} while (greaterZero(x));
```